# How can I move the inline item to the top right?

Tags: html, css

```css
#google1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
#google {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 200px auto;
  position: relative;
}
#gsearch {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
#form {
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  color: #7e7070;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none
}
#topbar {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
#grid,
#bell {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>GOOGLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="google">
        <img src="google1.jpg" img id="google1" alt="google1"/>

        <div id="form">
            <form action="" method="post" name="gsearch"></form>
            <input type="text" input id="gsearch" name="gsearch">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="grid.png" alt="grid" img id="grid"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="bell.png" alt="bell" img id="bell"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is align the `bell.png` and `grid.png` with the other text links to the top right of how google home page would look like.

Right now it displays at the bottom left inline. I have tried absolute positioning, but then I would have to fine tune it with top and left adjustments to get it right.

**Q:** Is there a simpler way of moving the entire block to the top right and align it?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>GOOGLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="google">
        <img src="google1.jpg" img id="google1" alt="google1"/>

        <div id="form">
            <form action="" method="post" name="gsearch"></form>
            <input type="text" input id="gsearch" name="gsearch">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="grid.png" alt="grid" img id="grid"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="bell.png" alt="bell" img id="bell"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS** code is as follows:

```
#google1{
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
}

#google{
    text-align: center;
    margin:200px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#gsearch{
    height:30px;
    width:50%;
}

#form{
    text-align: center;
    top:-30px; position:relative;       
}

ul{
    list-style-type:none; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}

li{
    float:left;
}

a{
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    color:#7e7070;
}     

a:link{text-decoration: none}  
a:visited{text-decoration: none}

#topbar{        
    position:relative; right:0; top:0; margin-right: 200px;     
}

#grid, #bell{opacity:0.4;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: You mean you want everything at the bottom left moved to the top right?

Comment: Why won't you go with `position: absolute`?

Comment: @showdev yes, i want to have it displayed top right.  If you open a new google page, the way it looks with our name and gmail etc on top right, i want to make it look like that.

Comment: @ManojKumar is that the best option? i noticed your reply below and i tried that as well.  But i was curious if that is the cleanest way of solving this problem or if there was a better way of structuring this part of the code that it produces the same result.  thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is a good way or you can wrap it inside a header div, set a height for it and wrap this inside.

Comment: @ManojKumar bare with me as i am still in the learning phase..care to give a quick example of how a wrap inside header div would look like?  thank you!

Comment: Right Click and Inspect Element. Hover over the menu in Stack Overflow. You can see the code, I was suggesting that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `position: absolute` is the way to go.

```css
#google1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
#google {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 200px auto;
  position: relative;
}
#gsearch {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
#form {
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  color: #7e7070;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none
}
#topbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#grid,
#bell {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>GOOGLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleg.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="grid.png" alt="grid" img id="grid"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="bell.png" alt="bell" img id="bell"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="google">
        <img src="google1.jpg" img id="google1" alt="google1"/>

        <div id="form">
            <form action="" method="post" name="gsearch"></form>
            <input type="text" input id="gsearch" name="gsearch">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your HTML and modified your CSS to place the nav elements at the top right. I set `text-align:right` on `#topbar` so that the items will be aligned to the right side. I also set the `<li>` elements to `display:inline-block` so that they will all appear on the same line but still accept some `margin`.

```css
#google1 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
#google {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 200px auto;
  position: relative;
}
#gsearch {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
form#search_form {
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  position: relative;
}

#topbar {
  text-align:right;
}
#topbar ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#topbar ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 0 0 1em;
}
#topbar ul li a {
  color: #7e7070;
  text-decoration: none
}


#topbar ul li a #grid,
#topbar ul li a #bell {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Shan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="grid.png" alt="grid" img id="grid"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="bell.png" alt="bell" img id="bell"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="google">
    <img src="google1.jpg" id="google1" alt="google1" />
    <form action="" method="post" name="gsearch" id="search_form">
      <input type="text" input id="gsearch" name="gsearch">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```